# Disable Buttons on Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, button, tabs, toplevel

I want to be able to able and disable buttons if the user inserted any data on my program, the problem is that i'm working with tabs, and the user can see 2 or 50 tabs at the same time so everytime they create a new tab, there's a command to create the same 8 buttons under the same variable name. (And the new tab also has the same variable name, but i keep track of them by putting them on a list.) Everything runs perfectly, but i just want to disable the button after the user insert any data. Is there a way to keep track of any buttons ID or address by tab in tkinter?

Here's the simplified model of what i'm using:

```
`from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Entrevista():
    def printaa():
        print(d.get())                                
        top.grab_release()                                                     
        top.destroy()                                                 
    global top
    top=Toplevel()                                                          
    top.grab_set()                                                         
    Label(top, text="Quem entrevistou o/a paciente").grid(column=0,row=0) 
    d = Entry(top, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)                            
    d.grid(column = 0, row = 1)                                             
    teste = Button(top,text="Inserir",command = printaa)                    
    teste.grid(column =1,row=1)                                             

def procurar():
    i=0                                                                 
    aba2 = ttk.Frame(abas)   
    abas.add(aba2,text=e.get())                                                                         
    entrev = Button(aba2,text="Entrevista",command = Entrevista)                
    entrev.grid(column =0,row=1) 

principal = Tk()
abas = ttk.Notebook(principal)                                                          
abas.grid(column =0, row = 0)                                                           
aba1=Frame(abas,width=500,height=500)                                                   
abas.add(aba1, text='Menu Principal')                                                   

e = Entry(aba1, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)                                            
e.grid(column = 0, row = 1)                                                            
b = Button(aba1,text="Procurar",command = procurar)                                  
b.grid(column =1,row=1)
principal.mainloop()`
```

Basically, I just want the "entrev" btn to be disabled after i insert any data, no matter what tab i'm in.

Comment: If you want 'entrev ' to be disabled then when do you want it to be enabled?

Comment: I want it to be enable, then will generate a toplevel to insert data, and after data, it will disable it.